# customize Legend in MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am working in project in project that needs implement chart , I decide use [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) its work just fine but I need some things done to be perfect to me

**First** can I change bars to specific image or it takes just images , as I have 3D image as bars in app design .

**Second** Can I put the legend to the right of chart in two line like image below and change legend text color

my java code

```
mChart = (BarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        mChart.setDescription("");
        Legend mLegend = mChart.getLegend();
        //mLegend.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART_CENTER);
FillBarChart(mChart);
}


private void FillBarChart(BarChart barChart) {
        ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        entries.add(new BarEntry(87f, 0));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(90f, 1));


        ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
        labels.add("Omeprazole 20 mg");
        labels.add("Esomeprazole 40 mg");

        BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, " ");
        dataSet.setBarSpacePercent(40f);
        BarData barData = new BarData(labels, dataSet);
        dataSet.setColors(new int[]{R.color.omeprazole_color , R.color.esomeprazole_color} , getActivity());
        barChart.setData(barData);
        barChart.animateY(3000 , Easing.EasingOption.EaseOutBack );
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that if you create a custom [`Chart`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/Chart.java) class and overwrite the `init()`.
In this method, the Chart initializes a [`LegendRenderer`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/LegendRenderer.java) and this is the point you need to get in and make changes.

Create a custom [`LegendRenderer`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/LegendRenderer.java) and make sure that all the measurements are in place for those drawable. `drawForm()` method will allow you to draw the images instead of the default forms (Circle, Square, Line).