# MPChart draw values Customisation - Horizontal Stacked BarChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPChart library for plotting horizontal stacked bar chart . Till now I have achieved the display of the horizontal stacked bar chart according to the requirements but blocked on custom legend views below the chart with a line indicator. I am attaching image of the desired result , any help would be appreciated.

**Desired Result**
[image: Desired Result]

**Achieved result**
[image: Achieved result]

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ4gk.png)
[Achieved result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziAID.png)

```
private fun setupMealtimeDistributionGraph() {
    val entries = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
    entries.add(BarEntry(0f, floatArrayOf(10f, 30f, 10f, 30f, 20f)))

    val set = BarDataSet(entries, "")
    set.colors = mutableListOf(
        ContextCompat.getColor(activity!!.applicationContext, R.color.blue_300),
        ContextCompat.getColor(activity!!.applicationContext, R.color.green_300),
        ContextCompat.getColor(activity!!.applicationContext, R.color.orange_300),
        ContextCompat.getColor(activity!!.applicationContext, R.color.indigo_200),
        ContextCompat.getColor(activity!!.applicationContext, R.color.indigo_300)
    )
    val data = BarData(set)
    data.setDrawValues(false)
    data.isHighlightEnabled = false
    mealtimeDistributionChart.data = data
    mealtimeDistributionChart.axisLeft.setDrawGridLines(false)
    mealtimeDistributionChart.xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
    mealtimeDistributionChart.description.isEnabled = false
    mealtimeDistributionChart.axisLeft.setDrawLabels(false)
    mealtimeDistributionChart.axisRight.setDrawLabels(false)
    mealtimeDistributionChart.xAxis.setDrawLabels(false)
    mealtimeDistributionChart.legend.isEnabled = false
    mealtimeDistributionChart.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: you have to create custom view for that mpchart do not support custom legends as of now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [customize Legend in MPAndroidChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197312/customize-legend-in-mpandroidchart)